# High-voltage oscilloscope probe

Tags: oscilloscope, high-voltage, probe

I need to measure a high-voltage signal (1kV) with an oscilloscope without a commercial high voltage probe. So I have to design my own 100:1 probe.
The oscilloscope has an input impedance of 1MOhm and 26pF capacitance.
I was thinking of a design like this:
[image]

With replacing the 9MOhm with 99MOhm, in order to get a 100:1 voltage divider.

However, I also saw designs like this:

[image]

Which one is better?

And how can I handle it if I have to measure this signal with AC coupling?

Comment: Homebrew high-voltage probes involve safety too, not just for your oscilloscope, but for **you**.

Comment: The second one loads the HV circuit more, but might make it easier to compensate. Either way you probably have to split R1 into multiple series R's to achieve a suitable voltage rating (more like 5kV than 1kV). Proper probe will be safer. If you're at work or college, liability and insurance will make it much cheaper too.

Comment: Proper construction techniques are more important than the schematic when dealing with dangerous voltages to avoid arcing and getting shocked. If you are not familiar with these, then it is recommended that you get a commercial probe. Also, you have not said what bandwidth you need which will also greatly influence the make/buy decision.

Comment: A commercial high-voltage passive probe really isn't that expensive. On a quick search, I found [this generic 250 MHz one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/tpi-test-products-int/P250/274483) for $43, rated to cat II 1500 V, and if you want something from a more trusted brand, there's [this 400 MHz one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/teledyne-lecroy/HVP120/5182357) from LeCroy for $461, rated to cat I 6 kV/cat II 1 kV. And there are plenty of other probes in between those two in price and probably also between them in quality.

Comment: Just get a probe. Generic x100 passive probes are cheap and work just fine. The schematic means almost nothing as far as *your* safety is concerned. You've completely neglected the actual probe body.